# Making a cost matrix in graph

Tags: algorithm, tree

**Problem** :
Form a network, that is,  all the bases should be reachable from every base. 
One base is reachable from other base if there is a path of tunnels connecting bases. 
Bases are suppose based on a 2-D plane having integer coordinates. 
Cost of building tunnels between two bases are coordinates (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is min{ |x1-x2|, |y1-y2| }.

What is the minimum cost such that a network is formed.

```
1 ≤ N ≤ 100000   // Number of bases
-10^9 ≤ xi,yi ≤ 10^9
```

Typical **Kruskal's minimum spanning tree** implementation.But u cannot store (10^5)^2 edges.
So how i should make my cost matrix , how to make a graph  so i can apply Kruskal algorithm?

Comment: Are you sure it's `min{...}` and not `max{...}`? Because if it's `min` that makes for a very strange answer.

Comment: @user3386109 ya it is min

Answer (score 1):

You should not store the whole graph as you don't actually need it. In fact in this case I think [Prim's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) algorithm is more suitable in this case. You will not need all the edges at any single time, instead on each iteration you will update a min dist array of size `N`. Of course complexity will still be in the order of `N**2` but at least memory will not be an issue. Also you can further use the specific way distance is computed to improve the complexity(using some ordered structure to store the points).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only edges that will ever be used (due to your cost function) will be from each base to at most 4 neighbours.  The neighbours to use are the closest point with greater (or equal) x value, the closest point with smaller (or equal) x value, the closest point with greater (or equal) y value, the closest point with smaller (or equal) y value.

You can compute these neighbours efficiently by sorting the points according to each axis and then linking each point with the point ahead and behind it in sorted order.

It does not matter if there is more than one point at a particular value of coordinate.

There will therefore be only O(4n) edges for you to consider with Kruskal's algorithm.

Comment: i have implemented this by sorting x and y [Here have a look](http://ideone.com/QZi8U3) but it is giving me a time limit exceeded error